# Read 1 line ahead while on current line using TextFieldParser

Tags: vb.net, csv

Is there a way to read ahead to the next line of a csv fine while still being on the current line? I need to insert some info into a database but I need a value from the line ahead...

```
Using MyReader As New 
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("D:\TEMP\HB\" & fName.ToString)
                MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
                Dim currentRow As String()
                While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                        nextRow = ?????

                End While
```

Comment: Will you always have a even number of records in that CSV? Or the *next line* is skipped after the *look-ahead*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any such function in the `TextFieldParser` class.
Anyway remember that as soon as you `ReadFields()` into `currentRow`, the file cursor is moved to the next line so when your code reach `nextRow = ?????` instruction the file cursor is already on that row. If you need to read the content of that row without "consuming" it, you can use the `PeekChars(n)` function wich will read "n" chars from the current line without moving the cursors position, leaving the line still usable from a following `ReadFields()` call.